# Check x is divisible by y

Tags: ruby

I want to check if x divided by y is a whole number, but if I just do `x / y`, it gives me an integer. But if I do `x.to_f / y`, it gives me a float, even if it's a whole number.

How can I divide a number and only get a float if it's not a whole number?

Basically what I'm trying to do is check if a number is divisible by another, so if you have a better way of doing this please let me know :)

Answer (score 6):

Found out

if `x % y == 0` it's divisible

Comment: For some context: `%` is the *modulo* operator which calculates the remainder of `x` divided by `y`.

Comment: What if `y = 0`?

Answer (score 1):

Or you might want to use

```
x.modulo(y).zero?
```